# Eloquent, multiple where clause with newest record

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel, I have a simple call that hits the userRecord table with a given email and grabs the first one.

This works but I want to check the created_at column and valid column as well to get the newest one that's valid (newest created_at date where today is before the valid date)

Existing line:

```
$get= (userRecord::where('email', $request->query->get('email')->where(curdate() < 'valid'))->first());
```

So rather than just getting the first, I want to add those column conditions. But I can't quite reconcile how to use the multiple where conditions and replace the first() call with just the newest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel you can make multiple wheres like this:

`->where([['first_where'],['second_where'],['n_where']])`

About the newest:

You can order by the `created_at` and use `desc` (bigger to small) like this:

`->orderBy('created_at','desc')`

And then, you can use the `first` method

Comment: Thanks, trying this now!